# Notice: Undefined variable: post_object & Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, variables

I'm getting two errors which are undefined variable & trying to get property of non object.

The troublemaker is `$post_object`

These are the lines that are causing me trouble. This code is working perfectly on localhost (using mamp) and a personal server, but are returning errors when I try to run the code on another server. I believe it is because the other one is more "strict" (ie. not accepting `<?` instead of `<?php`) but I'm kinda stuck here.

In such case, what would be the **appropriate** way to declare my variable to be able to use it?

```
<?
    // get posts
    $post_array = getArray($slug, $filter, $order);

    // display posts
    foreach ($post_array as $i => $post_object)

    {
?>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <h4><a href="<?=$post_object->title_link?>"><?=$post_object->title?></a></h4>
            <p><?=$post_object->content?></p>
            <div style="width: 100%;"><div><?=$post_object->tags?></div></div>
        </div>
        <input class="timestamp" type="hidden" value="<?=($i*10)+1?>"/>
        <input class="title" type="hidden" value="<?=$post_object->title?>"/>
<?
    }
?>
```

Comment: update your question to include the actual errors

Comment: What if you just put php while opening php tags so it would be easy to understand.. <?php

Comment: What PHP versions are you running?

Comment: @BasheerKharoti `<?=$var?>` is the same as `<?php echo $var; ?>`

Comment: Have you var_dumped `$post_array` ? (`var_dump($post_array);`)

Comment: @Jan I appreciate...

Comment: If short tags aren't enabled and you are running this on PHP >5.4 than you enter `<?=$post_object->title_link?>` without the `foreach` loop so undefined makes sense. `<?= before PHP 5.4.0, which is identical to <? echo. Use of this shortcut required short_open_tag to be on. Since PHP 5.4.0, <?= is always available.`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment as I don't have enough reputation.

You seem to be accessing the values as objects, but you name things in your code as array?

To access values in an object you use

```
$post_object->title;
```

but if it's an array you would use

```
$post_object['array'];
```

Not sure if this helps.

Comment: I know you are *commenting*, but if this is not an answer it's going to be flagged and probably removed.

Answer (score 0):

I probably am missing some of the details, but it appears that the biggest risk is the assumption that `$port_object` is an object and the proper type of object.

Assuming this is the case my best recommendation is to insert a check verifying that the `$post_object` is the correct object by using the [is_object()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php) and [get_class()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) function.  I don't know what the actual object name so i'm going to assume that it is "Post" in the example below:

```
<?
    // get posts
    $post_array = getArray($slug, $filter, $order);

    // display posts
    foreach ($post_array as $i => $post_object)

    {
        if(is_object($post_object) == false || get_class($post_object) != 'Post' ) {
            continue;
        }
?>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <h4><a href="<?=$post_object->title_link?>"><?=$post_object->title?></a></h4>
            <p><?=$post_object->content?></p>
            <div style="width: 100%;"><div><?=$post_object->tags?></div></div>
        </div>
        <input class="timestamp" type="hidden" value="<?=($i*10)+1?>"/>
        <input class="title" type="hidden" value="<?=$post_object->title?>"/>
<?
    }
?>
```

The check will cause the loop to skip any invalid objects.  Additional steps can be performed within the check to deal with other data structures.

I would also recommend using `var_dump($_post_object)`  to or even `var_dump($post_array)` to identify what is actually in the the variable.